# Solution to polynomial equation

Tags: symmetric-polynomials, groebner-basis

I have the following quite simply looking equation

$$ \frac{c_1 d_1}{c_2+c_3}=\frac{c_2 d_2}{c_1+c_3} = \frac{c_3 d_3}{c_2+c_1}$$

and I want to solve it for $c_1, c_2,c_3$. I know that these equations are homogen in $c$, hence I'm only looking for a solution up to scaling.

All $c_i$ are positive and I know that there exists a (unique up to scaling) solution. The $d_i$ come from a more complicated equation and might in some special cases cause trouble.
I'm only interested in the general solution, not in special cases, that is the cases where $d_i$ cause difficulties can be ignored.

Because the equation looks simple I expect a "simple" symmetric solution (I know that this doesn't have to be the case).

So far I tried solving the first equation for $c_3$ which is easy as it is linear. Then I inserted this into the other remaining equation, this however results in a polinomial of degree 3. With somewhat ugly coefficients. I tried to solve this polinomial but it gets quite dirty, so I asked a mathematical algebra tool (python sympy), it's no been computing since 10 minutes without a result, so I doubt it will come up with a good solution.

Is there an easy way to guess the solution?

I heard of the Groebner basis, but don't know how to apply it (that is I don't even know exactly what it is, just that it's a tool to solve polynomial equations in multiple dimensions). Can one apply this theory here?

Comment: What sort of solutions do you want? Real, complex, rational? A Gröbner basis might be handy, but there's a fairly good chance the solution subroutine you used in scipy is already trying to use one.

Comment: @N8tron The solution should be positive (i.e. $c_i>0$). I proved that this solution must exist and be unique (essentially I'm working on a more general topic and this is supposed to be an example of the broader theory, that's why I know that there must be a positive solution. The proof of that however is quite long so I didn't imclude it.

Comment: @JürgMerlinSpaak If the solutions are based on scaling, then you can assume that $c_1=1$ or $c_1=-1$ or $c_1=0$ which is just checking 3 cases

Comment: @Adam I tried that already, my sympy solver was still not able to solve it (btw. as mentioned in the comment above I'm only interessted in the case $c_1=1$)

Answer (score 3):

Let
\begin{align} 
\frac{c_1d_1}{c_2+c_3}&=k
\tag{1}\label{1}
,\\
\frac{c_2d_2}{c_3+c_1}&=k
\tag{2}\label{2}
,\\
\frac{c_3d_3}{c_1+c_2}&=k
\tag{3}\label{3}
.
\end{align}

Solution of the system \eqref{1},\eqref{2}
gives

\begin{align} 
c_1 &= \frac{kc_3(k+d_2)}{d_1d_2-k^2}
\tag{4}\label{4}
,\\ 
c_2 &= \frac{kc_3(k+d_1)}{d_1d_2-k^2}
\tag{5}\label{5}
,
\end{align}

substitution of \eqref{4},\eqref{5} into \eqref{3}
gives cubic equation

\begin{align} 
2k^3+(d_1+d_2+d_3)k^2-d_1d_2d_3&=0
\end{align}

which has at least one real root.
Given that, 
\eqref{4}, \eqref{5}
express $c_1,c_2$ in terms of 
$d_1,d_2,d_3$ and 
arbitrary $c_3$.

Comment: A quick addition. You could use cardano's formula to get an exact solution for $k$ though it is less efficient than most numerical algorithms and you'd have to change variables to make a depressed cubic equation first. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#math_Cardano's_formula

Comment: @N8tron: Thanks, but the solution of the cubic equation
is well-covered topic and it is presumed that OP is aware of that.